# neo4j v2.3.3 import failed

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j version - 2.3.3,
Windows 10

I exported the whole DB using the following command:

```
Neo4jShell -c dump > export_data.cypher
```

It did ok and created the file with cypher commands. What I tried to do is load import my data back using the following command:

```
Neo4jShell -file export_data.cypher -v
```

But it didn't work. Here is the error:

```
    WARNING: Invalid input 'c': expected whitespace, comment, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 1 (offset: 58))
"create (_193:`Entity`:`Role` {`Entity`:"Tag", `ID`:1739, `Name`:"Delete_Tag"})"
 ^
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
org.neo4j.shell.ShellException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
        at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.Commit.fail(Commit.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.Commit.exec(Commit.java:86)
        at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.NonTransactionProvidingApp.execute(NonTransactionProvidingApp.java:32)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractAppServer.interpretLine(AbstractAppServer.java:126)
        at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.GraphDatabaseShellServer.interpretLine(GraphDatabaseShellServer.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemotelyAvailableServer.interpretLine(RemotelyAvailableServer.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.interpretLine(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:149)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:133)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.executeCommandStream(StartClient.java:424)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.grabPromptOrJustExecuteCommand(StartClient.java:403)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:361)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:226)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:145)

 -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost)
 -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337)
 -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell)
 -pid       Process ID to connect to
 -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits
 -file      File containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After executing it the shell exits
 -readonly  Connect in readonly mode (only for connecting with -path)
 -path      Points to a neo4j db path so that a local server can be started there
 -config    Points to a config file when starting a local server

Example arguments for remote:
        -port 1337
        -host 192.168.1.234 -port 1337 -name shell
        -host localhost -readonly
        ...or no arguments for default values
Example arguments for local:
        -path /path/to/db
        -path /path/to/db -config /path/to/neo4j.config
        -path /path/to/db -readonly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround. But I don't think this is an elegant way doing it. What I did I just removed the line which contained the cypher code for creating the index. After that line is removed the dumped file can be imported successfully using the following command:`Neo4jShell -file export_data.cypher -v`

Hope this will help someone. But other than that this is not a solution.